# ¿Cómo poder guardar un usuario para iniciar sesion solo ingresando la contraseña en Java?

Tags: java, mysql, login

Me surgió una idea que quisiera implementar (por capricho que funcione de esa manera), quisiera hacer un sistema cuyo login guardara el usuario y al salir se quedara guardado tu usuario (no importa si hayas cerrado tu sistema al iniciar tienes guardado el usuario) y/o poder vincular mas cuentas en el sistema.

Recurro a esta plataforma para que me pudieran ayudar que recursos puedo utilizar para llegar a concretar mi idea.

La idea es realizarlo en Java, dejo una imagen mas o menos de como seria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Realmente la plataforma es para resolver dudas de programación, es decir que ya tiene que haberlo intentado y mostrar su código.
Pero se podría hacer con cookies.

Comment: @Jonathanch De hecho he realizado Logins de Manera clásica, pero esta vez me surgio la duda y la quiero implementar, no busco que me hagan el código, mas bien una referencia a seguir e investigar mas.

Comment: Pregunta, el sistema sería una aplicación local, una aplicación web... Depende de eso, se puede resolver de unas formas u otras

Comment: @Shirkam la idea es hacerlo en una red local, pero me interesaria que la persona hiciera sesión una vez y se guardara sus datos, y ya solo ingresara su contraseña algo similar a lo de Windows 10 y el pin.

Comment: En ese caso, como lo mejor es hacer lo que dice @Jonathanch, usar cookies o archivos ocultos solo con el último usuario que ha hecho login